# Buying commodities of lean hogs

Tags: halacha, transactions, business, non-kosher-species

Is there any halachic problem with buying or selling commodities of lean hogs?

Commodities are similar to the stock exchange, except one trades commodities such as wheat or crude oil.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85151/1362 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43533/participating-in-a-non-kosher-food-co-op

Comment: Gambling can be problematic for a number of reasons

Comment: This [article](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/18504) addresses your question with sources.

Comment: Are you making a direct, immediate purchase of this commodity or do you mean taking a position via futures contracts? If futures contracts, are you doing this directly, or are you buying an ETF that holds contracts as its underlying assets?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem from the Halachic literature that the problem of selling non-kosher food or animals is only if there's a risk of eating the non-kosher things one sells.

If one is a middle-man then it's permitted.

It would seem that commodities are at least as removed as a middle-man form the actual hogs. There's not a chance you'll be getting near enough to one of them to risk eating them.

For a final decision, please consult a reliable Rabbi.

Source: [Yoreh De'ah 117](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.117.1?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and the commentators ibid.